# Postgres INTERVAL YEAR TO SECOND issue with 8601 value 'P0Y'

Tags: postgresql

I think postgres is rendering INTERVAL MONTH TO YEAR in 8601 format incorrectly

```
yadamu=# SET intervalstyle = 'iso_8601';
SET
yadamu=# create table "OE1".T (I INTERVAL YEAR TO MONTH);
CREATE TABLE
yadamu=# insert into "OE1".T values ('P0Y');
INSERT 0 1
yadamu=# select * from "OE1".T;
  i
------
 PT0S
(1 row)
```

I would have expected this to return 'P0Y', not 'PT0S'

Comment: The two values are equivalent.  If you want to force the representation, then apply `TO_CHAR()`

Comment: Can you provide the correct TO_CHAR syntax, simply placing the column inside a to_char does not work..

Comment: try `to_char(T, 'PFMYYYY"Y"')`